# Undefined behavior when calling FD_ISSET

Tags: c, select, undefined-behavior

I've got a program with a Heisenbug I'm trying to diagnose.  Using a combination of gdb and Ghidra, I've been able to track down the crash to a particular section.  Here's the gist of my code:

```c
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(sock1, &readfds);
max_fd = sock1;

if ( some_condition ) {
    FD_SET(sock2, &readfds);
    if ( sock2 > max_fd ) {
        max_fd = sock2;
    }
}

if ( select(max_fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timer) == -1 ) {
    goto error;
}

if ( FD_ISSET(sock1, &readfds) ) {
    ...
}

if ( FD_ISSET(sock2, &readfds) ) {
    ...
}
```

I've been able to narrow down the crash to the expansion of that last `FD_ISSET` macro.  Specifically, it calls `__fdelt_chk` which ultimately leads to my shell reporting

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
```

However, if I change the code to

```c
bool using_sock2 = false;

...

if ( some_condition ) {
    using_sock2 = true;
    ...
}

...

if ( using_sock2 && FD_ISSET(sock2, &readfds) ) {
    ...
}
```

the problem goes away.

Clearly, I've invoked some kind of undefined behavior.  However, I looked at the man page and I didn't see any warnings/requirements that seemed relevant.  What exactly is causing this crash?

EDIT: Running the program under gdb or valgrind makes the error go away.  The only way I've been unable to locate the source of the crash is by running the program normally and then attaching with gdb from another terminal.

Comment: Please provide a MRE ( [mre] ) to demonstrate the misbehaviour.

Comment: Also, try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Either sock2 is invalid, or readfds is invalid. Check of sock2 is being closed. Or readfds is out of scope or (if allocated on the heap) being freed. Just for testing - declare both sock2 and readfds as static and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, @moi was right.  I managed to attach with strace and discovered that `close` was being called on `sock2` and then `sock2` was set to `-1`.  Voting to close due to "caused by typo" (close enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to be careful with fd_set/FD_SET/FD_ISSET is that these sets are fixed size -- there's only enough room for FD_SETSIZE file decriptors in the fd_set.  On Linux (you don't say what OS you are using) FD_SETSIZE is 1024, which matches the default ulimit of 1024 file descriptors, so you won't see problems UNLESS you've gone and raised the ulimit for your process (1024 is just a soft limit -- the hard limit is actually much larger).

If this *might* be the case, you should always check to make sure `fd < FD_SETSIZE` *before* calling FD_SET.  Something like:

```
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
if (sock1 >= FD_SETSIZE) {
    error("too many file descriptors!");
    abort(); }
FD_SET(sock1, &readfds);
max_fd = sock1;

if ( some_condition ) {
    if (sock2 >= FD_SETSIZE) {
        error("too many file descriptors!");
        abort(); }
    FD_SET(sock2, &readfds);
    if ( sock2 > max_fd ) {
        max_fd = sock2;
    }
}
```

You might also want to make sure that none of your file descriptors are some other invalid value (such as -1 that might come from an error in some earlier system call) as that would likewise cause an out-of-bounds access in the fd_set if you tried to use it with FD_SET or FD_ISSET